# atomic vs variable pass by ref. in <thread>

Tags: multithreading, c++11, pthreads, shared-memory, atomic

I want to write a program where, random numbers are going to be created and I am going to track down the greatest of them. Three threads are going to run in parallel.

I do it with two methods. First I create a variable in main(), which then I pass by ref. to every thread. At the end, this variable holds the maximum value generated. When the variable is updated, I use a mutex (do I really have to?).

The second method uses std::atomic and produces the same results (as far as I tested it).

This is a minor example I do, in order to use in my project, where it is **critical** that all the threads can see the current best value found by all the threads.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex
#include <atomic>
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine generator((unsigned int)time(0));
int random(int n) {
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, n);
  return distribution(generator);
}

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section
std::atomic<int> at_best(0);

void update_cur_best(int& cur_best, int a, int b) {
  // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
  if(cur_best > a && cur_best > b)
    return;
  if(at_best > a && at_best > b)
        return;
  int best;
  if(a > b)
    best = a;
  else
    best = b;
  mtx.lock();
  cur_best = best;
  mtx.unlock();


  // or

  if(a > b)
    at_best = a;
  else
    at_best = b;
}

void run(int max, int& best) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        update_cur_best(best, random(max), random(max));
    }
}

//g++ -std=c++0x -pthread px.cpp -o px
int main ()
{
  int best = 0;
  std::thread th1 (run, 100, std::ref(best));
  std::thread th2 (run, 100, std::ref(best));
  std::thread th3 (run, 100, std::ref(best));

  th1.join();
  th2.join();
  th3.join();

  std::cout << "best = " << best << std::endl;
  std::cout << "at_best = " << at_best << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The questions:

1. Are the two methods equivalent?

   From the  [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/): "Atomic
   types are types that encapsulate a value whose access is guaranteed
   to not cause data races and can be used to synchronize memory
   accesses among different threads."

   Are they equivalent by terms of
   the results they produce and efficiency?
2. If they are, then why is atomic introduced? What method should I
   use? Speed is what I am interested in.
3. Is there any faster method to achieve this functionality?

Remember that for my actual project, the point is that `best` will have the current best value from all the threads, in order to make comparison easier.

Comment: `th1` can write `best` (holding `mtx`) while `th2` reads `best` (without needing to hold `mtx`). This is a data race which is undefined behavior. You need to extend the critical section to all of `update_cur_best`. That said changing `best` to an `atomic<int>` will make the mutex unnecessary and increase performance.

Comment: So you say that the atomic method should be the one to choose. If so, answer the question, in order to have a full answer @nwp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [the data race @nwp pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733388/atomic-vs-variable-pass-by-ref-in-thread/25734875#comment40233616_25733388), you have data races on `generator` and `distribution`: the standard random number generators and distributions are not safe to be concurrently updated by multiple threads. This issue is easily addressed by creating a random number generator/distribution for each thread. You also need to ensure that the comparison and update of the global "current maximum" value are atomic, e.g., with [`compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaddad85440024b9)):

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <atomic>
#include <random>
#include <array>

void update_cur_best(std::atomic<int>& best, int a, int b) {
  if (a < b) {
    a = b;
  }

  auto cur_best = best.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  while (cur_best < a && !best.compare_exchange_weak(cur_best, a))
    ;
}

void run(int max, std::atomic<int>& best) {
  std::mt19937 generator{std::random_device{}()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution{0, max};

  for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    update_cur_best(best, distribution(generator), distribution(generator));
  }
}

//g++ -std=c++0x -pthread px.cpp -o px
int main()
{
  std::atomic<int> best{0};
  const int max = 100;
  std::array<std::thread, 3> threads;

  for (auto& t : threads) {
      t = std::thread(run, max, std::ref(best));
  }

  for (auto& t : threads) {
      t.join();
  }

  std::cout << "best = " << best << std::endl;
}
```

The update magic is in the [`compare_exchange_weak`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) loop:

```
  auto cur_best = best.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
  while (cur_best < a && !best.compare_exchange_weak(cur_best, a))
    ;
```

It will update the value of `best` to `a` if and only if the current value is `cur_best`. Otherwise, `cur_best` gets updated to the current value of `best` and the loop tries again. Effectively, `best` will only be updated if some other thread has not set it to a value greater than `a` before this thread tries to update.

Comment: I will have to read some theory of memory_order_relaxed and compare_exchange_weak, but I got the big picture! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as using mutexes: you are reading `cur_best` outside of the mutex and updating it while holding the mutex - that's not going to work.

And for using atomics:

While reading or updating an atomic variable is atomic with respect to those things happening conncurrently, each individual read or update is atomic - the atomicity doesn't hold across separate expressions.

So, for example, the expression in `if(at_best > a && at_best > b)` might resolve to `true` (and I'm ignoring the fact that `at_best` could return different values for each of the times it's evaluated in that expression), by the time the thread gets to executing:

```
if(a > b)
    at_best = a;
else
    at_best = b;
```

The atomic variable `at_best` might have been updated by another thread, and this one might be overwriting it with a smaller value. Now the larger value set by the other thread will be lost forever.

Comment: So, you mean that both methods are wrong. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: @G.Samaras Just use a lock. When you want to do a "read, compare, maybe update" operation, take the lock, do the operation, then release it.

Comment: If all you really want to do is have threads track the max number in an independent series, then have each thread determine its own max (which requires no sharing of state with anything else if you use separate RNGs), then each thread can report back its max. This can also be done with no sharing by passing into the thread some object to hold the result. When the thread is joined, that object can be queried to see if the thread's max is larger then the 'global' max. The end result is each thread does its work without interfering with the others, and no sync is needed except the joins.

Comment: That's what I thought too David. What Michael states is also VERY interesting. You see @MichaelBurr, I want that for my actual project. In the problem presented in the question, you are right. Worth some testing!